# Is Bsc from Netherlands in Computer Science eligible for M S from USA

Tags: masters

Hi My son will be joining Bsc in computer science from TU Delft Netherlands after completing 12 years of school education from India. Will he be eligible for MS after his graduation from. US universities?

Comment: For what it's worth, someone I know went from a computing science BSc. in the Netherlands directly to a PhD position in the UK.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably dependent on the institution.  You may have to check with each college or university you apply.  Also, check with the department too, don't ask general admissions.